# create a new single character shortcut (like ~)

Tags: bash, sh, cd

In BASH, is it possible to create a custom single character shortcut to a specific path, the way ~ is a shortcut to /home/myuser?

What I would like to do is have ^ (or whatever) be a shortcut to a directory /home/myuser/links that contains many symbolic links to directories I commonly use, so cd ^/currentproject would take me into a symbolic link to my current work, etc.

Comment: See [Create another shortcut `~~` like `~` (home directory)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232838/create-another-shortcut-like-home-directory)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you may want more is `CDPATH=:~/links`. And then `cd currentproject` would take you there. (Personally, I use a shell function I've named `pr` to take me to project directories and set up other environment settings specific to each project, but YMMV.)

Answer (score 2):

Make a function of 1 letter, something like

```
r() {
   cd ~/links/"$1"
}
```

Use it with

```
r currentproject
```